# jQuery-UI multi-range slider - fetch values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-range-jQuery-UI-Range-Slider.html) jQuery-UI plugin for my multi-range input. It works nice, except for one part, I can't fetch its values. Has anybody used this plugin? How do I fetch values to use them in my program? I can't seem to find method that fetches data. There is no documentation that describes how to do it.

```
var ranges_array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    startValue: 2000,
    endValue: 8000,
    color: "rgb(27, 64, 194)"
  }
];
//
$(function() {
  $('#budget-range').rangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    ranges: ranges_array
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your rangeSlider, you can create `rangeSlide` events that can read the values of the slider using the `ui` parameter on the event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentStartValue = '';
  var currentEndValue = '';

  $('#budget-range').rangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    ranges: ranges_array,
    rangeSlide: function(event, ui) {
      currentStartValue = ui.range.startValue; // set the current start value of the range
      currentEndValue = ui.range.endValue; // set the current end value of the range
    }
  });

  function logRangeValues() {
    console.log('Start value: ' + currentStartValue);
    console.log('End value: ' + currentEndValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I am still unsure how to use them. Do you mind telling me, how do I modify code so that I can  at some point  do this:  `console.log(startValue)` within some of my functions.

Comment: I updated the answer to include `console.log()` statements.  You can store these values in variables if you want to use them elsewhere in your program, but the `rangerSlide` event fires every time the slider range is changed, so that's your access point to getting the new values from the control

Comment: Updated the answer once more to store the values for later use and added a function for logging the values.  Hopefully this illustrates accessing the values at the point of change and storing them for other functions to use

Comment: No matter what I try, I can't seem to make it work with my Angular code

Comment: Maybe you can update your question to include your Angular code.  If you feel the problem you're facing now is different/changes your question, I'd suggest opening a new question